# Page using jQuery methods to store shared values to be re-used by the main controller method on reload

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 page with various links to different methods (one is the main method that forces a full reload of the page, others are Ajax methods).

These ajax methods do change some settings values and I wanted to store the new values on some hidden fields in the page so that the main method (when it reloads the page) can read them.

I'm currently not using a form so not I'm not sure if that's a problem.

Is there a way for the main controller to read the Request.MyHiddenValues to see if there are present, when it loads ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use cookies to perform your task.

When you change the value in ajax methods, update the cookies values, and then when the full page is loaded, check the **Request.Cookies** for the values.